# xmlhttprequest file upload not working on mobile

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to upload images using XMLHttpRequest, Everything works great on web browsers perfectly but it's not working on mobile phones.
showing progress percentage properly and there is no error found in LOG file.

Until a few days ago this code was working perfectly on all devices, I have been facing many problems since the hosting provider upgraded the system.

Please advise what went wrong,
Thank you.

**Javascript:**

```
function fileSelected() {
    var count = document.getElementById('attachment').files.length;
    if( count > 0 ){
        $("#attachment").prop('disabled', true);
        
        $('#submitButton').hide();
        $('#uploadButton').show();
    }
}

function uploadFile() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("attachment", document.getElementById('attachment').files[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");
    xhr.send(fd);
}

function uploadProgress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = Math.round(e.loaded * 100 / e.total);
        document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = '<b>Attachment</b> ' + percentComplete.toString() + '% Uploaded';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
    }
}

function uploadComplete(e) {
    var resp    = e.target.responseText;
    var respArr = resp.split('-');
    
    if( respArr[0] == "successful" ){
        $("#uploadedAttachment").val(respArr[1]);
        $('#submitButton').show();
        $('#uploadButton').hide();
        document.getElementById("upload_file").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function uploadFailed(e) {
    alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
}

function uploadCanceled(e) {
    alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
}
```

**upload.php**

```
if (isset($_FILES['attachment'])) {
    $file_tmp       = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
    $file_with_ext  = explode(".", $_FILES['attachment']['name']);
    $file_ext       = strtolower($file_with_ext[1]);
    $file_name_new  = md5(uniqid().mt_rand()).".".$file_ext;
    
    move_uploaded_file( $file_tmp, "attachments/" . $file_name_new );
    echo "successful-{$file_name_new}";
}
```

**Form:**

```
<form id="AddComplaint" name="AddComplaint" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="field" id="upload_file">
        <div class="ui action input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Browse_Picture">
            <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" onchange="fileSelected();" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="hidden" id="uploadedAttachment" name="rec[uploadedAttachment]" value="" />
        <div id="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <button type="button" id="uploadButton" style="display:none;" onclick="uploadFile()"><i aria-hidden="true" class="upload icon"></i><span>UPLOAD</span></button>
        <button type="submit" id="submitButton"><i aria-hidden="true" class="send icon"></i><span">SEND</span></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the following lines in the users.ini file and the issue was fixed successfully.

```
memory_limit = 128M 
max_input_vars = 2000
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 120
```